# IDM CC extension is not working in Tor browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security, configuration, browsers

IDM CC which is used to work fine with Mozilla browser, is not working in Tor browser, even though it is successfully installed in Tor browser. For an example, when a video is being played the IDM download extension is not coming up.

Answer (score 1):

Dear just use previous version of IDMCC extension. like IDMCC 7.3.89 version.

Don't use previous version of IDM, just use old version of IDMCC file.
the latest version of IDMCC is 7.3.91